# Macros in MonoDevelop T4 templates

Tags: mono, monodevelop, t4

When running a T4 template in MonoDevelop that includes path macros, i.e ${ProjectDir},  ${TargetFileName}

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="${ProjectDir}${OutDir}${TargetFileName}" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #> 
...
```

MonoDevelop spits out the following error:

```
Running generator 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator'
error CS0006: Metadata file `${ProjectDir}${OutDir}${TargetFileName}' could not be found
```

I have tried using both curly and round braces. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming you are not using a preprocessed template: Did your project build sucessfully before transforming the template? T4 templates are transformed at design time, so if the build failed there is no assembly that could be loaded.

Comment: @Nico yes, the project builds fine. I think the error suggests that the T4 tool isnt even processing the macros.